# Rails routes related to a search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

On my latest web site I have a search form defined like this:

```
= form_tag search_path(:termen), :method => :get do
  = text_field_tag :termen, params[:termen]
  = submit_tag "Search »"
```

And a route:

```
# search
get "search(/:termen)" => "articole#cauta", :as => :search
```

I want when I press the search button to be get to a url like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/search/[the_termn_that_was_typed]
```

So for example when I am searching "vampires" I should get:

```
http://www.mysite.com/search/vampire
```

Any clues on this one?

Thank you a lot,

Comment: Isn't it working? What are you getting?

Comment: Going directly to the url works, but pressing search get's me to http://www.mysite.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&termen=vampire&commit=Search%C4%83+%C2%BB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that RESTful way of doing this is to make redirect of posted request to get request with constructed url you want it to be.

Here are two routes

```
resources :articles do
  collection do 
    get :search, :action => 'search_post', :as => 'search_post'
    get 'search/:q', :action => 'search', :as => 'search'
  end
end
```

Now in the controller you redirect the post request to get request

```
def search_post
  redirect_to search_articles_path(params[:q])
end
```

As a result of submitting the form user ends up on the url

```
http://www.mysite.com/articles/search/vampire
```

Comment: If I need to use two params how can I use this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get around this when using a form directly, because that's just how the parameters are submitted. You could do it with a bit of javascript though. I'll offer a solution that I feel is a bit clunky, and you can decide if it's worthwhile or not.

First the js (using jQuery):

```
$(".search_submit").click(function(){
  var button     = $(this);
  var form       = button.closest("form");
  var action     = form.attr("action");
  var text_field = form.find(".search_text");
  var value      = text_field.val();

  window.location = action + "/" + value;
  return false;
});
```

And then your view code would just need to add the appropriate classes:

```
= form_tag search_path(:termen), :method => :get do
  = text_field_tag :termen, params[:termen], :class => "search_text"
  = submit_tag "Search »", :class => "search_submit"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I do think I will need some encoding on the search string thow, thanks