# rails parameterize form data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application that allows searching of posts when a get request in the form of `/posts/search/:searchstring` is recieved. I have no problems with the functionality when I put the search string in using my browser's url bar, but I am stuck trying to create a search form.

How can I make an html form in rails that allows me to send a get request using the above syntax? Am I going to be stuck using a controller method to redirect?  I really want this functionality because I am a firm believer that the URL is a part of the UX and I hate ugly URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=searchstring&commit=Search
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails routes related to a search form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064303/rails-routes-related-to-a-search-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form's gonna do what a form's gonna do, and if you have a form using GET, it's gonna serialize those parameters into the query string.

But since you *are* using get, you also don't truly need to submit the form.  Rather you can just send the browser to the URL.

So for example, somewhere in your JS:

```
function doSearch(form) {
  // This assumes that the first input of your form is the search
  // box.  YMMV.
  var query = encodeURIComponent(form.elements[0].value);

  // just send the browser to the constructed URL
  window.location = form.action + "/" + query;

  // and return false to prevent the actual submit
  return false;
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<form action = "/posts/search" onsubmit="return doSearch(this)">
  <input type="text" name="searchstring" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I like this but what if there are spaces and special characters in the search string? How will those be handled?

Comment: That's where encodeURIComponent comes in.  It will escape such characters.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the form this way:

```
<form method="get" action="<%= search_posts_url_path %>">#text input here with name "searchstring"</form>
```